# How do I use use multiple lines in a jq filter file?

Tags: json, bash, command-line-interface, jq

I'm reading [the jq manual](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/) and it says:

> ```
> -f filename / --from-file filename:
> ```
>
> Read filter from the file rather than from a command line, like awk's
> -f option. You can also use '#' to make comments.

I typed this into my command line:

```
$ cat input.json | jq -rf filter.jq
```

and my `filter.jq` file is:

```
.signal[] | .name
# .signal[] | select(.name | contains("signal")) as $matches
```

This gives me an error:

```
$ cat input.json | jq -rf filter.jq 
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:

jq: 1 compile error
```

If I append `\` to the end of the first line, I get a different error:

```
$ cat input.json | jq -rf filter.jq 
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
                  \
jq: 1 compile error
```

I also tried `\\`, with similar results.

The only fix I found is to merge the two lines into one. But this limits my ability to document my filter and use the file as a playground for experimentation. How do I use use multiple lines in a jq filter file?

---

Note: I have tried this on both cygwin and WSL and get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `filter.jq` contains DOS line endings. Strip them using the `dos2unix` utility or run your script using the Windows build; `jq-win64.exe` from the [releases page](https://github.com/jqlang/jq/releases) works fine on both Cygwin and WSL2.

Comment: Was there something in the error message that helped you understand that?

Comment: @DanielKaplan The empty line between `jq: error: ...` and `jq: ...` shows that the syntax error was caused by whitespace. The culprit is often DOS line endings in such cases.